# sql query when building column names dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have many DB tables with the following columns names format:
val_0_start, val_0_end, val_1_start, val_1_end... val_100_start, val_100_end.

I need to select the different between the end and the start for each value:
select val_0_end - val_0_start,... val_100_end - val_100_start.

Is there an easy way to do it instead of writing all the diffs, something like:
select val_[0-100]*end - val*[0-100)_start

I didn't design the tables nor can change them.

Comment: There is not shortcut  .. the only way is building the query dinamically  using procedural code  ..

Comment: what @scaisEdge said is correct you're gonna need to do it through code or a stored procedure.